# jScrollPane won't reinitialise

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I've somehow struggled with jScrollPane everytime I've used it in the past, but always managed to make it work in the end.  This time however I'm completely stumped and hoping someone can enlighten me.

I have some animated items on my page, that after executing load external data into a div (#content).  I believe I've initialised and then re-initialise correctly after animation completes but I get nothing.  Everything else fires correctly except for jScrollPane.  Here's the CSS:

```
#content { margin-top: 30px; position: absolute; left: 120px; right: 20px; max-width: 900px !important; height:300px; overflow: auto; z-index: 99; }
```

And here's the js:

```
g_index = -1;


$(function() {

//jscrollpane settings
var settings =
{
    // showArrows: true
};
var pane = $('#content')
pane.jScrollPane(settings);
var api = pane.data('jsp');

$('#nav > .circle').mouseenter(

function () {

    var index = $(".circle").index(this);
    var $this = $(this);

if(index != g_index) {

    g_index = index;

    $('.circle a').removeClass('engtext');
    $('#content, #bgimage').fadeOut(250, function() {
    $('#bgimage').removeClass('bgl bgr');
    });
    $('.animate').stop().animate({
        'width'     :'100px',
        'height'    :'100px',
        'top'       :'0px',
        'left'      :'0px',
        'opacity'   :'1.0'
    },1000,'easeOutQuad',function(){
        //animation complete
    });

    $this.find('a').addClass('engtext');
    $this.find('.animate').stop().animate({
        'width'     :'1100px',
        'height'    :'1100px',
        'top'       :'-300px',
        'left'      :'-300px',
        'opacity'   :'0.7'
    },500,'easeOutQuad',function(){
        //animation complete
        var target = $this.find('a').attr('href');
        target = target.replace('#','');
        $('#content').css('left', (index * 120) + 120 );
        $('#content').load(target + '.html', function() {
                // when target page has loaded do the below
                $(this).fadeIn(250);
                api.reinitialise();

                if(g_index < 2) {
                    $('#bgimage').addClass('bgr');
                    $('#bgimage').attr('src','img/footer_' + target + '.png');
                }
                else {
                    $('#bgimage').addClass('bgl');
                    $('#bgimage').attr('src','img/footer_' + target + '.png');
                }
                $('#bgimage').fadeIn(250);
        });

        //all animation complete
        $('.animate').filter(':animated').promise().done(function() {
            $('.circle').removeClass('z1');
            $this.addClass('z1');
        });

    });

}

});

});
```

Comment: So you are not getting data? or your animations are not working?

Comment: Is 'target' variable retrieving the exact name in order to complete your load function?. 'target + .html'

Comment: Animations are working and the correct page is being loaded into div#content, the only thing that is not appearing is the customised scrollbar.  If I remove jscrollpane the browser displays its normal scrollbar on div#content.